# Return multiple array to Response::json laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-4

How we can return multiple array in json.
Suppose we get the following response in Laravel eloquent:

```
$user= User::all();
$post= Post::all();
$comment= Comment:all();
```

Now I want to return response in json which include these data:

```
Response::json(array('user'=>$user,'post'=>$post,'comment'=>$comment));
```

Using the above method empty value is returned. Any help would be appreciated

Sorry guys. I found the solution. The data that I was passing was already in object form. Therefore I needed to convert it into an array and then pass it.

```
$user= User::all()->toArray();
$post= Post::all()->toArray();
$comment= Comment:all()->toArray();
```

Now it will work!

Comment: It looks good, where do you see the Null? Usual issue with JSON is if there is any "echo"s in the method, double check for any debug messages.

Comment: Response is like {"user":{},"post":{},"comment":{}}. it's not null but response is showing nothing.Iam getting output when i simple echo these results.

Comment: debug your data, try switch the $users with a simple array('one', 'two'). Try `print_r($post);die;` just before the `Response::...` .

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity.data that iam passing is already in object form, first i need to convert it into array and then pass it in json_encode.Anyway Thanks for your attention. cheers!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

i think you can try this method:

```
$user= User::all()->toArray();
$post= Post::all()->toArray();
$comment= Comment:all()->toArray();

Response::json(['user'=>$user,'post'=>$post,'comment'=>$comment]);
```